# How to give make my KVM guests can connect to host?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have IP address in host (Centos 6.8)

```
 em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:17:EB:AE:89:6C  
      inet addr:172.16.32.53  Bcast:172.16.32.255   Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::3617:ebff:feae:896c/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:171364 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:139801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:201751985 (192.4 MiB)  TX bytes:15156935 (14.4 MiB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7f00000-f7f20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:6672 (6.5 KiB)  TX bytes:6672 (6.5 KiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:3A:25:C8  
      inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

and my guest in KVM (Centos 6.8):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:28:27:12  
      inet addr:172.16.32.27  Bcast:172.16.32.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe28:2712/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:558 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:37491 (36.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1021 (1021.0 b)
      Interrupt:11 Base address:0x4000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

My host and my guest can connect to internet, but my host cannot ping to my guest in KVM, and setting from my guest[my bridge setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogqOQ.png) is :

What should i do to make  my host can ping to my guest? Because when i ping to guest, my host just show destination unreacheable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use Bridge for your guests
A `Linux Bridge` device is a virtual switch, it bridge your host and guest to a same network

First new a Linux Bridge in your host, more info [Manually Creating a CentOS 6 Network Bridge](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_CentOS_6_KVM_Networked_Bridge_Interface)

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.f8bc1212c3c0   no      bond0
```

Then, you can set your guest NIC to use the bridge `br0`, don't forget to reboot the guest after this done

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry because i'm newbie in KVM and i want to learn. Thank you for your answer. It help me.

Comment: If the solution is good for you, please marking it useful.